# Trac spawning for nginx deployement without using tracd

Tags: python, wsgi, trac, spawning

I am trying to run Trac on nginx.

There is a simple solution that consists of running the tracd server, but I'm trying to avoid that. It doesn't support unix sockets.

Instead, I'm trying to use [Spawning](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning) that should be able to launch any WSGI application.

But I don't know how to use it. After [deplyement](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#cgi-bin), I have my `cgi-bin` directory with `trac.wsgi` in it, but I don't know how to launch it using Spawning.

It doesn't accept a file name as an argument, I have to provide the module and the application names, like `spawning my_module.my_wsgi_app`. But how do I do it with trac.wsgi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading Spawning docs I saw that it receives on the command line, as the first parameter, the *dotted name* of your application's WSGI object. Especifically for Trac, the WSGI object is defined at `trac.web.main.dispatch_request` [[1]](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser//trunk/trac/web/main.py#L326). Try passing this to Spawning.

But remember that Trac needs some environ variables in order to run correctly, to name a few: `TRAC_ENV`, pointing to your Trac Environment and `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE`, where Python will estract any loaded egg file.

Since Spawning does not receive a file as the first argument, you won't need `trac.wsgi`.

You can try this, running directly from you shell.

```
$ TRAC_ENV=/path/to/your/trac-env PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp/.egg-cache spawning trac.web.main.dispatch_request
```

Good luck!